# Designing a survey form for channel partners in SharePoint

Tags: survey, online

Is there a way by which the channel partners like vendors could login to SharePoint to fill a Survey form?

Any suggestions on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: share those forms with their(vendors) external email id and give them permission to add list items

Comment: I have verified SharePoint isn't allowing to give access to email's external to active directory.

Comment: Of course It allows. To turn on external sharing,You should have tenant admin access. Then you can turn on external sharing. then you can share forms to external users